# regular expressions in Python - I want to find variants of 'yo mama' and replace it

Tags: python, regex, replace, expression

Rather uh, odd question. I have strings of 'your mother' jokes and other such variants. I'd like to replace each instance of 'yo mama', 'your mother', 'your mum', etc with another string - let's just call this 'Fred' for now.

How can I go about doing this? I started with:

```
newComment = comment.replace('Your mama','Fred')
```

But I quickly realized this won't cover all instances. Could anyone offer some assistance with regex please? :)

These comment strings are made through a for loop via a web scraper. So far, the variants I've found are as follows - case sensitivity notwithstanding:

```
yo mama
You mama
Your mama
Your mother
Your mum
```

Bonus - I'd also like to replace 'she' with 'he' and 'her' with 'his'.

Comment: How many instances have you got ? I mean how many variations ?

Comment: You can rewrite this for all the possible variations.

Comment: We need some more information. Tell us about how does the data looks like. Is it a .txt file? How do you load it to your .py? How do you separate each 'joke', with commas?

Comment: Ah sorry. So I'm getting these through a web scraper and the results are filtered through a loop. Each one is a separate string and gets added to a list called 'yoMamaList' with an append statement. I'd like to edit each string before it gets added to yoMamaList.

Answer (score 4):

You can use capturing group and alternation for such problem **if there are less instances and you know them all.**

**Regex:** `(?:yo|your)\s*(?:mama|mother|mum)`

- `(?:yo|your)` possible instances of first word separated by alternation.
- `(?:mama|mother|mum)` same with second word.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mb78lM/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

You could go for

```
[Yy]ou?r? (?:m[au]ma?|mother)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/co3YiF/1).

Answer (score -1):

If you have got lots of variations, you should avoid regex. Instead store the list of all your `instances` in a `list` and iterate over the list doing a `replace` operation over all the elements in the list.

```
List= ['yo mama','your mama']
for rep in List:
    newComment=comment.replace(rep,'Fred')
```

For changing the gender - **BONUS**

```
newComment=comment.replace('she','he').replace('her','his')
```

Comment: @CristiFati typo. Sorry.

Comment: This is better than using regex where one has to manually alter words.

Comment: @Rahul If a lot of instance words are to be replaced, a non-regex way would be less confusing and more easier to code, at the same efficiency if not better

Comment: Agreed ! That's why I mentioned **if there are less instances and you know them all.**

Comment: @Rahul True, but the asker already added 6 instances. A joke is a generic data, and can have many instances to be replaced with 'Fred'.